# How to upload a file in c++?

Tags: c++, file

I am trying to upload a file which contains some questions and their answers.
I wrote this code but I don't know what the problem is. It is my first time using files.

```
#include <string>
#include <vectors>

/*
 This is a function I am using.
 I want to upload the file contents in these vectors 
 The file has a questions and 4 answers so the questions is in one vector 
 and each answer is in a different vector.
*/

string readfile(vector<string> &q1, vector<string> &a1, vector<string> &a2,
                vector<string> &a3, vector<string> &a4) {
  string line, filename;
  ifstream file;

  cout << "enter file name:";

  cin.ignore();

  getline(cin, filename);

  file.open(filename.c_str());

  if (file.fail()) {
    cout << "Unable to open file datafile.txt\n\n" << endl;
  } else {
    while (getline(file, line)) {
      if (line.size() > 0) {
        getline(file, line);

        q1.push_back(line);

        if (line.size() > 0) {
          getline(file, line);

          a1.push_back(line);
        }
        if (line.size() > 0) {
          getline(file, line);

          a2.push_back(line);
        }

        if (line.size() > 0) {
          getline(file, line);

          a3.push_back(line);
        }

        if (line.size() > 0) {
          getline(file, line);

          a4.push_back(line);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  file.close();
}
```

The outcome is always "Unable to open file data file .t x t"

Comment: We have no idea what you inputted as the file name.  What did you input as the file name?  Also, you would be better off if you input the full path name of the file, not just "datafile.txt".

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your code doesn't contain a `main` function and you should remove the `else` part.

Comment: There exists no header `vectors`. You forgot the namespace `std`. You forgot the header for `fstream`. The function has return type `string` but doesn't return anything...

Answer (score 0):

You are ignoring input:

```
cin.ignore();
```

If you remove that line of code it will read correctly the name of the file you want to open.